# How can you display traffic for a route using the Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to show traffic along a route using the Google Maps JavaScript API? So far, the only way I've found to show traffic is to show the traffic layer for the entire map. I would like the route to appear similar to how it does in the Google Maps website, where the actual route itself changes colors depending on the traffic conditions at that point.

My website is using the sample code from the [Google Maps Autocomplete Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions). How could the code be modified to show traffic for the route?

The only way I've found to display the traffic so far is to use

```
var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);
```

but that shows it for the entire map instead of just my route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to display traffic only for a route using the Google Maps JavaScript API, as you said, you can show traffic for a city but not singles streets.